# how to fetch data in october cms laravel

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am new in October cms.
how to fetch data from **Code section** to **Markup section.**
I want to print email value in markup section

page name is : questionnaire

Markup section

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">

    <p>{{ email }}</p> 
    <div class="module-contact well">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div id="partialContactForm">

    </div>
</div>
```

Code section is below

```
 function onStart(){

     $data['users'] = DB::table('users')->get();
     $email = $data['users'][0]->email;
}
```

Comment: Use **$this** built in variable to store values and access them in markup section. **$this['email'] = $data['users'][0]->email;**.  Refer Docs https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/themes#php-section

Comment: how to fetch  $data['users'] in markup section, it will fetch all users details

Comment: Take a clear look at the previous comment $data['users'] **[0]** , this will only hold the 0th record of the data fetched from db. In case if you want to get only one record you should try to use **first()** method to fetch sql data rather than **get()**. Refer docs https://octobercms.com/docs/database/query#retrieving-results

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign it to a new key in the `$this` variable and it will be available in your view.

```
function onStart() {
    $this['email'] = 'Your string';
}
==
Email: {email}
```